# How do I distinguish a mail header from a MIME header in Perl MIME::Tools?

Tags: perl, email, mime

In MIME::Tools parsing an email gives you a MIME::Entity consisting of MIME::Head and MIME::Body. As per [MIME::Head#NOTES](https://metacpan.org/pod/MIME::Head#NOTES) email headers and MIME headers are considered the same thing.

For me these two are very different things:

- An email header is something that contains "From:", "To:" and "Subject:". In this case the Body ist the non-attachment part of the message, something that gets displayed in a mail program.
- a MIME header ist something that contains "Content-Type:", "Content-Disposition:" and "Content-Transfer-Encoding". In this case the Body is an attachment, which MAY be displayed in a mail program but typically gets stored somewhere through "Save as ...".

For the moment I assume that a MIME::Head is an email header and the parts contain MIME headers unless `is_multipart` is signaled: then MIME::head of that part is an email header.

But that seems a bit ... heuristic to me. Is there a better way to distinguish both?

Here is my current code:

```
use MIME::Parser;

$parser = new MIME::Parser;
dissect_message($parser->read(\*STDIN), 1);

sub dissect_message {
    $message=shift;
    $is_mail_header=shift;
    
    $body_name="BODY";
    if($head = $message->head) {
        if($is_mail_header) {
            # Output mail HEADER
        } elsif($head->recommended_filename) {
            # This is a MIME header
            $body_name=$head->recommended_filename;
        }
    }
    
    if($body = $message->bodyhandle) {
        open(BODY, $body_name)
        print BODY $body->as_string;
        close(BODY);
    }
    
    @p=$message->parts;
    for($i=0; $i <= $#p; $i++) {
        $p=$p[$i];
        dissect_message($p, $p->is_multipart);
    }
}
```

Comment: A mail header is always a MIME header. But not every MIME header is also a mail header - only the outer MIME header or the one within message/rfc822 attachments.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Are you saying that the above code is correct and not heuristic?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve with the heuristics. If you interested in getting the outer header of a mail than the code is wrong since you treat multipart MIME the same as outer header.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich What I am trying to achieve is (not to use heuristics but) to distinguish mail headers from other MIME headers the correct way. So far the code seems to do that. I attached a mail to a mail (this gets send as an *.eml) and the code reacts correctly. But I would very much appreciate a more correct code example or a hint how to do so.

Comment: A "full" mail with a mail header is either the outmost thing or contained inside a message/rfc822 part. So for heuristics you need to check the content type.